# Create dependency for task defined by gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I'm applying a gradle plugin in my `build.gradle` file which supplies three tasks (one for each build variant), and I want to make sure those tasks run each time the build task finishes. Furthermore, I have another task I created that I want to run whenever one of the plugin tasks completes. Here's the gradle file so far:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jaredsburrows.license'

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        // etc
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // etc
        }

        staging {
            // etc
        }

        release {
            // etc
        }
    }
}

task copyLicenseToSrc {
    doLast {
        // etc
    }
}

build.finalizedBy(tasks.findByName('licenseDebugReport'))
tasks.findByName('licenseDebugReport').finalizedBy(copyLicenseToSrc)
```

The `jaredsburrows` plugin produces the `license*Report` tasks. Whenever I try to reference either task with `tasks.getByName('licenseDebugReport)` or `tasks.getByName('licenseReleaseReport)` I get a task not found exception.

Here's a screenshot of the tasks pane for reference.

[image]

How can interact with the tasks defined by the plugin?

Comment: Twu question: **1.** Do you want to always run `licenseDebugReport` if `build` was run, or do you want to run `build` first if you run `licenseDebugReport`? **2.** Where exactly did you try that line you mentioned?

Comment: @Vampire If build runs, I want licenseDebugReport to run. I need a file generated by the licence task at runtime so it must always be generated. The line I mentioned was below the android scope in the build.gradle file for the subproject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the plugin adds those tasks delayed.

You can try three things that just come to my mind.

**1.** Try to delay further, doing your dependency settings in an `afterEvaluate { }` block which will be executed after the project is evaluated, but still inside the configuration phase.

**2.** You can just operate on all tasks of type `LicenseReportTask` by using `tasks.withType(LicenseReportTask) { build.finalizedBy it; it.finalizedBy copyLicense }`. This will be executed on all existing tasks of that type immediately and on all tasks that get added in the future as soon as they were added.

**3.** You can use the same mechanism the plugin is using, trying whether this works properly then using `android.libraryVariants.all { variant -> build.finalizedBy tasks."license${variant.name.capitalize()}Report"; tasks."license${variant.name.capitalize()}Report".finalizedBy copyLicense }`